Instagram Basic Display API return "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"
I have been trying to fetch posts from instagram user profiles that are not professional/business profiles.
I am using below url:
https://graph.instagram.com/USER_ID/media?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,permalink,timestamp&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN 
Instead of giving me posts it gives me this error:
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
Question: How can I use Instagram Basic Display API to fetch page or user posts without having the user to login through instagram or facebook?
